# parameter sweeping: rank parameters according to output

Tags: testing, sorting, parameters, combinations

I'm trying to find the best 3-tuple parameter combination for my algorithm. I have several results for each possible combination.  Right now I'm raking each tuple (x,y,z) according to highest number of successes first, in the following manner:

```
(x,y,z): ((1.0, 100 times), (0.8, 20 times), (0.5, 200 times), (0.0, 10 times))
(x1,y1,z1): ((1.0, 80 times), (0.9, 100 times), (0.5, 50 times), (0.0, 100 times))
(x2,y2,z2): ((1.0, 80 times), (0.9, 20 times), (0.5, 200 times), (0.0, 30 times))
```

...which means that for tuple (x,y,z) I had a success rate of 1.0 100 times, a success rate of 0.8 20 times, etc.

Now, I'm afraid such sorting is naive, in that it doesn't take into account that, for example in `(x1,y1,z1)` there's a high number of failures (0.0) along with a high number of successes (1.0).

How should I take this into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends a lot on your definition of "best"! Would you rather have an algorithm that always gives a 0.8 success 100% of the time, or one that gives a 1.0 success 80% of the time and a 0.0 failure 20% of the time, or are those equivalent for your purposes?

A very simple approach you could take would be a weighted sum of the results, like so:

```
rank = 0;
total_results = 0;
for each (success_rate, number_of_results_at_this_rate) in this_data; do
    rank += (success_rate * number_of_results_at_this_rate);
    total_results += number_of_results_at_this_rate;
done
rank = rank / total_results;
```

(Of course this can be simplified if total_results is always constant, as it is in your example above)

This would give you the following ranks for your example:

```
(x,y,z) = (100 + 16 + 100 + 0) / (100+20+200+10) = about 0.65
(x1,y1,z1) = (80 + 90 + 25 + 0) / (80+100+50+100) = about 0.59
(x2,y2,z2) = (80 + 18 + 100 + 0) / (80+20+200+30) = 0.6
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I made sure the number of results for each combination of parameters was always the same.

Comment: I was looking for a general answer, which you just gave, but in my particular case I know the output should be always 1.0, so it's not totally wrong to value that first. I worry about all the remaining output, though, especially when a lot of low values are present. Maybe I should stick with my sorting for (1.0, occurrences) and then apply something similar to your approach for the remaining values. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, if 1.0s are that important, the hybrid approach you suggest (sort by # of 1.0 results, then by weighted sum of all non-1.0 results) does seem plausible - so (x,y,z) would be preferred due to most 1.0 results, followed by (x2,y2,z2) with fewer 1.0s but a sum-of-all-others of 0.472, followed by (x1,y1,z1) with the same 1.0s as x2, but a sum of 0.46.

Comment: I'm still concerned by a possible case with the highest number of 1.0 and also highest number of 0.0s. How should I deal with that? There should be some kind of deranking, right?

Comment: As I said, the answer depends a lot on exactly what outcome you're trying to get. If you'd rather prefer an algorithm that yields slightly fewer 1.0 results in exchange for many fewer 0.0 results, you'll just need to incorporate that into your sorting somehow. A few possibilities: 1) sort by "# of 1.0 results - # of 0.0 results" as a first or second step, 2) assign 0.0 results a negative weight in the sum so they actively count against it instead of just not contributing, 3) pre-sort by "# of 0.0 results" and pre-emptively exclude the top N results before continuing with the rest of the sort.